# Given an array of chat rooms, and an array of chat room metadata, how can I securely update the corresponding chat room in both?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, websocket, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

To practice using Firebase for large-scale applications, I'm making a Firebase app that has multiple chat rooms, similar to [Firechat](https://firechat.firebaseapp.com/).

Theoretically there could be millions of chat rooms, each of which has millions of messages.

I would like to be able to display a list of chat room names, including some metadata about each chat room such as its number of participants.

The simplest way from a coding perspective would be to load all chat rooms, but that could be a tremendous amount of data.

My solution is to have an array of `Chat`s and an array of `ChatInfo`s. The former will contain all the chat messages, and the latter the metadata about each chat.

My question is: **How can I update an item in one array and be sure the corresponding item in the other array is also updated without relying so much on the client?**

My current solution is this:

```
var chatData = {room_name: "Test Room"}
var chat = Chat.ref.push(chatData);
var chatMeta = ChatMeta.ref.push(chatData);
chat.update({chat_meta_id: chatMeta.key});
chatMeta.update({chat_id: chat.key});
```

This works. However, it feels to me like **it relies too much on the client**.

For instance: What if the client's Firebase connection dies after the `Chat` has been created but before the `ChatMeta` has been created? Of course Firebase is near-instantly fast, but relying on front-end code to sync things up on the back-end feels like bad practice.

One solution would be to have all "write" requests go through a back-end server I control, and *then* go to Firebase. But the whole "no back end!" thing is such a big selling point for Firebase that I wonder whether that can be avoided.

To my mind, there should either be some way of doing a "shallow" query of all the different `Chat` items so that keeping a running list of `ChatMeta` data is unnecessary, or some kind of rule set up on Firebase's end that updates `ChatMeta` whenever `Chat` is updated. However, neither of those seem to exist.

Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't really read the entire question. But from a quick scan it looks like you're trying to perform atomic updates, which you can do with a multi-location `update()` call. See https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/09/introducing-multi-location-updates-and_86.html, https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/10/client-side-fan-out-for-data-consistency_73.html

Comment: Hi, Frank. Yes, I'm using `update`. However, my question isn't about `update` but rather whether there's a less client-reliant alternative.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid both relying on the client too much *and* having a controlled back-end server by using [Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/).

In this case, you'd create an `HTTP TRIGGER` function and you'd push your `room_name` to it from the client. The cloud function would perform your requirements and return the `ChatMeta` object.

Comment: Hmm. It's that pushing from the client that I'm trying to avoid, since it gives the client so much control. I suppose using the client to only read Firebase, and sending write requests to my server to forward to Firebase, is my best bet.

Comment: My suggestion is to send your write requests to the cloud function instead of your server so that you remain 'server-less'.